# I am unable to find such t moldings or reducer where it fits my laminate to tile transition

Tags: tile, trim, laminate, transition

I got this picture from another post and since I am new to this community I dont know much on how i can ask questions to existing posts or comments also it did not allow me to do so. 
Below is a picture which closely resembles to what I have. The distance between laminate and tile is 7/8th of an inch. So ideally I was looking for a T molding where one side is thicker(lets say something greater than 5/16" on one side and 5/16" on the other) and one side is thinner to cover up the height difference but I havent found something like this in Lowe's /Home Depot/Floor and decor. If anyone knows where I can found something as described please tell me ?

[image]

For using reducer of this kind If I can get something like below that would help too: 
[image]

Final question: Do you think the space left (7/8th inch) between laminate and tile is very small and if I make that wider then I would have more options on the reducer ?

Comment: build up the bare floor channel in the middle to the height of the tile (using shims, spare tile pieces, strips of underlayment, etc), then use the bottom trim.

Comment: Have a wood shop make a T with a thicker section one side to fit, they can rout a channel each side to different heights.

Comment: Just FYI - what you've done here is 'correct' as far as the Stack Exchange model goes - you have a new question, so you asked a new question. This is not a 'forum' type of site where you just tag onto the end of someone else's post.

Comment: I have to go with Mike on this. That is an awful big height difference to make up using standard transition pieces. Also most transition pieces are 2" wide, you would need a wider one for a smoother transition.

Comment: Hey @dandavis  thats a nice suggestion on building up the floor channel in the middle but after I do that what shops sell such trims ? I checked home depot/lowes/floor and decor and could not find such trims. Thats the main problem for me.

Comment: @solarMike How do I find such wood shops ?

Comment: Thanks @brhans for your support.

Comment: May be even some of the home depot type pkaces will do that - have to ask, if not they may have a suggestion. Not worth me saying who I would got to as I know many tradies... If not the yellow pages ie phone book...

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/TrafficMASTER-72-in-Tile-to-Laminate-Hardwood-Transition-18503/202066501

Comment: @dandavis thanks for link, the only concern I have is the space I have left between the laminate and tile is very small (7/8th") and so the one you shared link has widthness more than that.

Comment: DO you all think that the space width (between laminate and tile) I have is too small and if i make it little wider then I would have more options ? or current width of 7/8 inch is good enough for clean transition ?

Answer (score 1):

I've had that exact situation, and found that the only type of transition strips that allow for this kind of height difference are ones meant for carpets. They tend to be metal, but wood ones can also be found. Below is an example. You would still need to build up the gap in between a little in order to have some support underneath and have something for the nails to go into.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the picture, where did you find this ?

Comment: Are you in the US? I've bought mine at Menards, the picture I think showed up on the Home Depot site. Search for "Carpet Tranisition Strip".